# Space Between Bars in Bar Chart in Google Visualization API

Tags: google-visualization

How to Add Space Between Bars in Bar Chart in Google Visualization API?
I have used group width option also but the space not increasing.

Comment: I tried the below code

Comment: where is the code? please edit the question to add the code -- it depends on the type of chart, if using _material_ chart, the options are not supported, see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)...

Comment: I am using column Bar charts.Now i got the solution.

Comment: Thank you WhiteHat for quick response.